# How to get URI from Drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I am working on an Android application where I deliver some built-in images and give the user the option to download some more from the web to use in the application. At some point in my app, I look at an ImageView in my layout and want to determine if the Drawable inside is an in-built resource or an image I have downloaded from the web to the SD Card.

Is there any way to extract the URI of the Drawable used in the ImageView? This way I would be able to see if it is a resource or a downloaded file.

Here is my code so far:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.content_img);
Drawable image = view.getDrawable();
```

UPDATE:
Using Barry Fruitman's suggestion from below, I stored the URI of the image directly inside my custom ImageView for later use. Here is what my implementation looks like:

```
public class MemoryImageView extends ImageView {
private String storedUri = null;

public MemoryImageView(Context context, String Uri) {
    super(context);
}

public MemoryImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MemoryImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public String getStoredUri() {
    return storedUri;
}

public void setStoredUri(String storedUri) {
    this.storedUri = storedUri;
}
```

}

And usage looks like this:

```
MemoryImageView view = (MemoryImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.content_img);
String img = view.getStoredUri();
if(img.startsWith("android.resource")) {
    //in-built resource
} else {
    //downloaded image
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once you create the Drawable that information is lost. What I suggest you do is subclass the ImageView and add extra member(s) to keep track of whatever you want.

Replace:

```
<ImageView />
```

with

```
<com.mypackage.MyImageView />
```

And create:

```
class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    protected final int LOCAL_IMAGE = 1;
    protected final int REMOTE_IMAGE = 2;
    protected int imageType;
}
```

MyImageView will behave exactly like an ImageView, but with that extra member that you can read and write anywhere you want. You will probably also have to override the ImageView contructor(s) with constructors that just call super().

Comment: Interesting solution, why are the LOCAL_IMAGE and REMOVE_IMAGE constants needed?

Comment: I just added those as an example of constant values you can assign to imageType. You can use any values you want (or even Strings or other datatypes). (REMOVE_IMAGE was supposed to be REMOTE_IMAGE. I just edited the post to fix that).

Comment: Thanks, I actually need the URI not just for that purpose but also to store in a DB, so I just kept it as a string in my View.